# objectatindex outside of loop?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsinteger

This is a question hard to ask but I'm going to give it a shot anyways. I'm trying to retrieving the contents of an `NSDictionary` outside of the UITableCell loop. Right now, when I do retrieve its content via:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
```

everything works fine. But outside of that loop, in a void function of its own, the number retrieved is 0.

```
- (void)getVideoList{



NSString *ensdsds = @"z9yDgV3ONSU";



for (int i=0; i< [self.youtubePaginator.results count]; i++){

    NSDictionary *photoshoots = [self.youtubePaginator.results objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString * videoId = photoshoots[@"videoID"];

    NSLog(@"Newly %@: ", videoId);



    NSString *urlStrings = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id%%2C+snippet%%2C+contentDetails%%2C+statistics&id=%@&key=78587868", videoId];

    NSLog(@"Arries %@", urlStrings);

    NSURL *urlstats = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStrings];
    NSURLRequest *requeststats = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlstats];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operationtwo = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:requeststats];
    operationtwo.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [operationtwo setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operationtwo, id responseObjected)
     {
         NSDictionary *itemed = [responseObjected objectForKey:@"items"];
         for (NSDictionary *itemest in itemed )
         {
             YouTubeVideo *youTubeVideo = [[YouTubeVideo alloc] init];
             NSDictionary* stats = [itemest objectForKey:@"statistics"];
             youTubeVideo.likesCount = [stats objectForKey:@"likeCount"];
             youTubeVideo.viewsCount = [stats objectForKey:@"viewCount"];

             NSDictionary* channelInfo = [itemest objectForKey:@"snippet"];
             youTubeVideo.channelInfo = [channelInfo objectForKey:@"channelId"];
             youTubeVideo.videoUploader = [channelInfo objectForKey:@"channelTitle"];


             NSLog(@"True To: %@", youTubeVideo.videoUploader);
             [self.thunder addObject:youTubeVideo];


         }} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {

         NSLog(@"Error loading %@", error);
     }];

    [operationtwo start];    }
```

}

The above code returns nothing. How do I incorporate `NSIndexPath` in the void function and still be able to call   `[self getVideoList];` in `viewDidLoad`.

Hope that makes sense? :/

Comment: You question is not making sense please try to elaborate your problem what exactly you are doing in cellForRowAtIndexPath and why you want to call [self getVideoList] in ViewDidLoad method?

Comment: I'm retrieving videos from YouTube. In cellForRowAt,     NSDictionary *youtubeInfo = [self.youtubePaginator.results objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger) indexPath.row][@"snippet"]; <- this works perfectly. I'm wondering how to do the same NSDictionary but outside of cellForRowAt

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `imageURL` in `getVideoList` by passing `NSIndexPath` as a parameter , you just need to create a global `NSString` object if you want to access it globally or you can return extracted `imageURL` as a return value.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        NSString * imageURL = [self getVideoList:indexPath];

        // Write your code to perform operation with the image URL.
}
```

Here is the `getVideoList` method

```
- (NSString *)getVideoList:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{    

    NSDictionary *photoshoots = [self.youtubePaginator.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.Row];
    NSString * imageURL = photoshoots[@"avatar_url"];
    NSLog(@"Newly %@: ", imageURL);

    NSLog(@"To find us: [%d]:%@",i,self.youtubePaginator.results[i]);

    return imageURL;
}
```

You can update the code as per your requirement.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply. I'm still stuck unfortunately. I've updated the code above. My question now is how do I use         NSString * imageURL = [self getVideoList:indexPath];
 in that void function?

Comment: I'm there to call the index from the void function instead of cellRow. If I put         NSString * imageURL = [self getVideoList:indexPath];
 in a regular void function, it says indexpath cannot be found.

Comment: Absolutely. Here it is: For the YouTube extraction, I'm using this: https://github.com/FelipeDocil/NMPaginator | to try and get the detail about each video, I'm using this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g182u85d2kduyde/ListView.zip?dl=0

Comment: It always worked in cellRow. What I really want is to have it work in the void function so I can do a new query!